# Sending dynamic content sms with twilio

Tags: ruby, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I am using Twilio SMS service for one of my projects it is in Ruby. In this, I want to send SMS with dynamic values like for example `Hi, {{name}}` in this name attributes will be dynamic. I have gone through the documentation but I am not able to figure it out how can I achieve this. I am using the ruby Twilio client library. However, I can send normal plan text SMS with it but not SMS having dynamic contents.
My current code is

```
@connection = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@connection.messages.create({
  :from => options.fetch(:from),
  :to => options.fetch(:to),
  :body => options.fetch(:body)
})
```

Comment: If you are calling the method from a ruby class, then you can pass the `name` attribute as a method parameter, so when you call the method that processes the SMS you only need to add the parameter. `user.send_message(name)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def welcome_message(name)
  "Hi, #{name}! welcome to our website."
end
```

And when you're passing the options:

```
options = {
  from: someone,
  to: someone,
  body: welcome_message(some_name),
}
```

Then the same snippet you shared:

```
@connection = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@connection.messages.create({
  :from => options.fetch(:from),
  :to => options.fetch(:to),
  :body => options.fetch(:body)
})
```